# 3D printer firmware version

Tags: programming, arduino-ide

Is there a way to determine which version of a Marlin firmware I would have installed onto my printer? I am trying to modify the existing arduino sketch rather than starting all over with a wrong, earlier version. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, check to see if the printer itself yields this information, either on LCD display if present, or by reporting it to a host computer upon connection (ie, try enabling verbose output in your printing software).

While it's not guaranteed to be supported, in practice many Arduino Mega based 3d printers have bootloaders capable of readback of the flashed contents, and the chips themselves are unlocked.  Even if the bootloader does not support this, an ISP connection might.

If you are able to read out the contents, you can have `avrdude` write them to a flat binary file, and examine it with the `strings` program or a hex editor.  If you end up with a hex file instead, there are tools for converting this to a flat binary.

Your goal would be to look through the file for version strings, and other messages which might indicate specifics, especially on which side of various points of change or configuration options it falls.

Making such a backup is a good idea before loading a new firmware anyway.  Ideally after verifying that you obtained meaningful contents, you would also readback a few distinct copies of the file and use something like `diff` to verify that they are all the same.  You can grab the EEPROM contents too, if your firmware may be storing things there.

Comment: Thanks. I can see the Marlin fw version in the lcd but not my arduino sketch version/name.

Comment: That may well not be saved.  Still, if you have a finite number of candidates you can try to look at details that would differentiate them.  Rebuilding and doing some kind of percentage fuzzy match comparison could work, but could also easily get confused by different compiler versions or build options.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I assumed my option was. Thanks.